# How to automatically create new Profile once a new User is created in Django?

Tags: django

Currently running into this issue with my Django app that I am working on.

I have a model class Profile that I want to be automatically created and assigned to a new user. Was wondering how I can do this? I do have a custom user model that I have set up as well.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by creating a signal:

This executes after saving a record of `User` model as `post_save` signal is used.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
       if created:
          Profile.objects.create(user=instance).save()
    except Exception as err:
       print(f'Error creating user profile!\n{err}')
```

Here `instance` is the user object, `sender` is the `User` model & `created` is a boolean object used to check is a new record is created after saving the User model on not.

You can get more information about it [over here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/).